Periodicity of the dual scalar in $T$-duality
This question concerns the dual scalar (Lagrange multiplier) field $\lambda$, which appears in discussions of $T$-duality (e.g. in section 7.5.1 of David Tong's notes where it is called $\tilde\phi$).
In particular, while it is clear that $\lambda$ cannot be non-compact, I am unable to understand why it must be $2\pi$-periodic.
Consider Lorentzian signature, with convention $\eta_{00}=1=-\eta_{11}$ and $\epsilon^{01}=1=-\epsilon^{10}$.
Consider a theory of maps $\phi : \mathbb{R} \times S^1 \to S^1$ with action functional
\begin{equation}
    S[\phi] = \int d^2x \frac{R^2}{2}(\partial\phi)^2.\tag{7.49}
\end{equation}
The aim is to identify conditions on the field $\lambda$ which yield equivalence of the functional integrals,
$$
\int[d\phi]e^{iS[\phi]}=\int[db][d\lambda]e^{iS[b,\lambda]}
$$
where
\begin{equation}
    S[b,\lambda] = 
    \int d^2x
    \left[
    \frac{R^2}{2}b^2 + \frac{1}{2\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\mu\partial_\nu\lambda
    \right].
\end{equation}
Contradiction argument: If $\lambda$ was a non-compact scalar, then functionally integrating over $\lambda$ produces a delta functional constraint $\delta[\epsilon^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu b_\nu]$. This means field configurations can be restricted to the form $b_\mu = \partial_\mu \phi$ for a non-compact scalar $\phi$. Thus, $\lambda$ cannot be non-compact.
I'll now list two unsuccessful approaches I've explored, which the assume that $\lambda$ is $2\pi$-periodic.
Approach 1: Integrating by parts and using a lattice discretization on the relevant part of functional integral gives
\begin{align}
\int [d\lambda]\exp\left[i\int d^2 x \frac{1}{2\pi} \lambda(\epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu b_\nu)\right]
& \sim
\prod_x \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\lambda(x) \exp\left[i\frac{1}{2\pi} \lambda(x) \epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu b_\nu(x)\right] \\
& = \prod_x \frac{2\pi i}{\lambda(x) \epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu b_\nu(x)}\left[1-e^{i\lambda(x) \epsilon^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu b_\nu(x)}\right]
\end{align}
This approach seems to be on the wrong track!
Approach 2: Again working on the lattice, attempt to incorporate periodicity of $\lambda$ via the derivative operator:
\begin{align}
    \int [d\lambda]\exp\left[i\int d^2 x \frac{1}{2\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\mu \partial_\nu \lambda\right]
    =
    \sum_{n_{x,\nu}}\prod_x \int_{-\pi}^\pi d \lambda_x \exp\left[i \sum_{x,\nu} \frac{1}{2\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\mu(\lambda_x - \lambda_{x+e_\nu}+2\pi n_{x,\nu})\right]
\end{align}
This appears more promising, although it is unclear how to proceed.
Approach 3 (following @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə):
Expand
\begin{align}
\lambda & = \sum_i \lambda_i \psi_i \\
b_\mu & = \sum_j \alpha_j Y_{\mu,j} + \sum_i \beta_i (\partial_\mu \psi_i)
\end{align}
where $\psi_i$ and $Y_{\mu,j}$ are orthonormalised (transversal) eigenfunctions.
Plugging into the action, integrating by parts and using antisymmetry of the permutation symbol and using the fact that $\partial_\nu$ kills the zero mode of $\lambda$, I get
\begin{align}
\int d^2 x \frac{1}{2\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\mu \partial_\nu \lambda 
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{i\neq 0} \sum_{j} \alpha_j \lambda_i \int d^2 x \, \epsilon^{\mu\nu} Y_{\mu,j}\partial_\nu \psi_i \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{i\neq 0} \lambda_i \int d^2 x \, \epsilon^{\mu\nu} b^\perp_\mu(x)\partial_\nu \psi_i
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
&\int[d\lambda]\exp\left[i\int d^2 x \frac{1}{2\pi} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\mu \partial_\nu \lambda\right]
 = \\
& \int d\lambda_0 \prod_{i\neq 0}\left[\int d\lambda_i
 \exp\left(i\frac{1}{2\pi}\lambda_i \int d^2 x \, \epsilon^{\mu\nu} b^\perp_\mu(x)\partial_\nu \psi_i \right)\right]
\end{align}
Finiteness of the functional integral seems to reaffirm the fact that $\lambda_0$ is compact. It's not clear to me how to proceed to show $2\pi$-periodicity, however.
Approach 4: An interesting observation is that if we integrate by parts on $\lambda$ and then demand that the functional $e^{i S[b,\lambda]}$ is invariant under the transformation $\lambda(x) \mapsto \lambda(x) + 2\pi$ then we obtain $$\exp\left[-\frac{i}{2\pi}\int d^2 x \partial_\mu (\epsilon^{\mu\nu}b_\nu)\right]=1$$ which is indeed equivalent to Tong's (7.51). I'm not sure what to make of this.

The easiest way to see the correct periodicity without introducing a lattice is to simply expand $\lambda$ and $b$ in orthonormalised (transversal) Laplacian eigenmodes (scalar and vector respectively) and then do the integral over the coefficients of the $\lambda$ modes. You will be left with a single $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ (after say zeta-function regularising) which needs to be cancelled by the volume of the zero-modes, i.e. the only constant mode. Hence that volume should be $2\pi$.

@ɪdɪətstrəʊlə that sounds promising but is a little cryptic to me. Do you know a reference that expands on this?

@ɪdɪətstrəʊlə I've started to explore your suggestion in Approach 3 of the OP but I'm getting stuck.

See 1611.05920 for some inspiration, albeit in a different theory - so most likely not helpful in your case. I don't have a better source tbh. However, one key thing that you may have missed is that you're on the cylinder so you can use the explicit form of the Laplacian eigenfunctions: $\sim e^{i \omega t + i k x}$ where $\omega$ is free but $k$ quantised. Hit it with a derivative and see what happens. The one-forms are similar so you can explicitly integrate them against one another.

@ɪdɪətstrəʊlə. I see, but even assuming that these integrals can be done, we're still left with the unknown coefficients \lambda_i and \alpha_j. Moreover, requiring finiteness of the functional integral only shows that \lambda_0 cannot be non-compact, which was already evident from the contradiction argument in the OP. I don't see any possible avenue to showing 2\pi-periodicity.

The coefficients are to be integrated over (they are regular integrals, not path integrals). If you have never done this computation I suggest you do it for a free non-compact scalar, say in 1d first. It shows the flavour of the computation. The upshot is, you're left with something like $\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus{0}} k^{-1}$ which via zeta-fuction regularisation gives $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. This is to be cancelled by the volume of the zero mode, i.e. the periodicity of $\lambda$.

Sorry, I misspoke. I meant to say that after integrating out \lambda_i we are still left with \alpha_j, but I suppose you are advocating integrating out those too. Even so, I'm not convinced by the approach because finiteness of the partition function only tells you that \lambda_0 is compact. It says nothing about its range or periodicity. In other words, you're basically assuming the answer.

I think I might see what you're aiming for now. Let $I_1=\int [d\phi]e^{iS[\phi]}$ and $I_2=\int [db][d\lambda]e^{iS[b,\lambda]}$. Is your proposal to show that $I_1=I_2$ if $\lambda$ is $2\pi$-periodic? That makes sense to me.


If λ
was a non-compact scalar, then functionally integrating over λ
produces a delta functional constraint $\delta[\epsilon_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}b_\nu]$
. This means field configurations can be restricted to the form $b_\mu=\partial_\mu\phi$
for a non-compact scalar $\phi$.  Thus, $\lambda$
cannot be non-compact.

First of all, the last sentence, the conclusion, is literally wrong.  Though depending on what OP really means, it could be a careless slip of tongue or genuine misunderstanding.
As long as $\phi$ is twice differentiable, Bianchi identity always holds and $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu} \phi = 0$ identically.  Compactification or not has no consequence on derivatives, where only an infinitesimal neighborhood of $\phi$ is concerned.
Now, I know that Tong specifically says he wants to relax Bianchi identity in order to allow for winding.  That is his slip of tongue.  What he really means is not a compact $\phi$ winding around the periodic spatial direction.  Rather, he wants to introduce instantons, which are singular configurations where the winding number around the spatial direction changes along the time axis.  An instanton in (1+1)-D Minkowski spacetime is topologically the same as a vortex in 2D Euclidean space, and that is where the meaning of "winding" gets mixed up.
The supposed modification to Bianchi identity reads
$$
\epsilon_{\mu\nu}\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu} \phi = 2\pi \sum_{i} n_i \delta(r - r_i),
$$
where $i$ labels the individual instanton, $n_i$ is its strength and $r_i$ its location in spacetime.
Go to imaginary time, and discretize the 2D Euclidean space on a square lattice.  The LHS $\epsilon_{ij}\partial_i\partial_j \phi$ is now the circulation of $\partial\phi$ around a plaquette, and should be an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  This fixes the periodicity of the corresponding Lagrange multiplier.
Edit: just want to mention that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\lambda \,e^{i2\pi\lambda X} \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(X - n)$, applied to every plaquette.
If anyone knows of a way to argue for this result without going through the lattice, I'd really love to know.

In the quoted segment, I think the OP actually meant that a compact scalar is really a zero-form connection, so it has to have a harmonic piece.

I now quote one more sentence.  My interpretation is, indeed, based specifically on OP's citing of Tong.  But the sentences does sound to me like: "if $\phi$ is compact, then $\epsilon_{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \phi \neq 0$".  Not true unless instantonic, singular configurations are inserted by hand.

The dual of compact boson is a "discrete" boson. For a full lattice treatment, I will Wick rotate to Euclidean space. The compact boson becomes the familiar XY model. On the lattice, the action is typically discretised with the corresponding measure (up to a multiplicative constant):
$$
S[\phi] = -J\sum_{\langle x,y\rangle}\cos(\phi_x-\phi_y) \\
d\mu \propto e^{-S[\phi]} \prod d\phi_x
$$
with $\phi_x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. However, the mathematical analogy is clearer with the Villain model:
$$
S[\phi] = -\frac J2\sum_{\langle x,y\rangle}(\phi_x-\phi_y+2\pi n_{xy})^2 \\
d\mu \propto e^{-S[\phi]} \prod d\phi_x
$$
where there is an additional field on the edges $n_{xy}\in\mathbb Z$. You can now set the gradient:
$$
b_{xy} = \phi_x-\phi_y+2\pi n_{xy}
$$
Essentially, $n$ is there to allow integer winding numbers while $\phi$ encodes the curl free part. To switch entirely to $b$, the periodic Bianchi identities need to be imposed on all loops:
$$
\sum_{(x,y)\in\square}b_{xy} \in 2\pi\mathbb Z
$$
This is done by inserting a Dirac comb using the Poisson summation formula:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \delta(t-2\pi n) = \frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{in t}
$$
so the measure becomes:
$$
d\mu \propto e^{-\hat S[b,\lambda]}\prod_{\langle x,y\rangle} db_{xy}
$$
with:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat S[b,\lambda] &= \frac J2\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}b_{xy}^2+i \sum_\square \tilde\phi_\square \sum_{(x,y)\in\square}b_{xy} \\
&=  \frac J2\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}b_{xy}^2+i\sum_{\langle X,Y\rangle}\epsilon_{xy,XY}(\tilde\phi_X-\tilde\phi_Y)b_{xy}
\end{align}
$$
with $X,Y$ represent faces (i.e. dual vertices), $\tilde\phi_X\in\mathbb Z$ and $\epsilon$ is there to impose that $(X,Y)$ and $(x,y)$ are dual edges (orthogonal). I integrated by parts to get the second line.
To finish the analogy, you can even integrate out the $b$ field. You therefore get:
$$
\mu \propto e^{-\tilde S[\tilde\phi]} \\
\tilde S[\tilde\phi] = \frac1{2J}\sum_{\langle X,Y\rangle}(\tilde\phi_X-\tilde\phi_Y)^2
$$
Had you continued with the usual cosine XY model, you would have ended up with the modified dual action:
$$
\tilde S[\tilde\phi] = \sum_{\langle X,Y\rangle}\ln\left(I_{\tilde\phi_X-\tilde\phi_Y}(J)\right)
$$
and $I$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Had you kept the Minkowski signature, the result would have been the same, you will just need to keep track of the signs.
Thus, viewing $\tilde\phi$ as the dual boson, $\tilde\phi$ is not $2\pi$-periodic but rather discrete with step $1$. In statistical physics, this is a well known fact. Integral loop curves of $\partial\phi$ are level lines of $\tilde\phi$. The discretisation of the circulation translates into the discrete steps $\tilde\phi$ can take. This is an example of a solid-on-solid model typically used for the surface roughening of crystals. More generally, a $T$ periodic boson is dual to a $2\pi/T$ discrete boson. This is consistent with the limit $T\to\infty$: a boson is dual to itself.
You can convert this to usual quantum mechanics by using continuous time but discrete space. If you start with the Hamiltonian ($V$ is a periodic potential):
$$
H = \sum\frac12p_k^2+V(\phi_k-\phi_{k-1})
$$
with $\phi$ $2\pi$-periodic and $p$ the conjugate discrete canonical momentum satisfying the Weyl uncertainty:
$$
e^{-i\phi_k}p_ke^{i\phi_k} = p_k+1
$$
Duality amounts to the change:
$$
\tilde\phi_k = p_{k+1}-p_k \quad p_k = \tilde\phi_k-\tilde\phi_{k-1}
$$
Now, it is $\tilde\phi$ which is discrete and $\tilde p_k$ which is periodic with the same uncertainty principle:
$$
e^{i\tilde p_k}\tilde \phi_ke^{-i\tilde p_k} = \tilde \phi_k+1
$$
And the Hamiltonian is now:
$$
H = \sum V(\tilde p_k)+\frac12(\tilde\phi_{k+1}-\tilde\phi_k)^2
$$
For example, to recover the cosine XY model, you just need to take $V=-J\cos$.
